# how to use google cloud console to run a python project

Tags: python, html, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have been using **python** to create a project the frontend is in **HTML**. Now that it is complete I would like to host it as an instance on **google cloud console**. I have already created a *project*, *storage bucket* and *vm instance* on the console, I just do not understand how to run my project on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Executing python code on a GCE instance is very easy. There is a [quick guide](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started) and lots of examples on [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python). [Accessing the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets) is very simple as well. I hope this helps.